# Polynomial approximation of a limit

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I am supposed to find the Taylor polynomial $P_2(x;1)$ for the exponent function $f(x)=e^x$ and use it in conjunction with Taylor's theorem to evaluate the following limit: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1} \frac{e^x-ex}{(x-1)^2}$$ The required polynomial I believe is $e+e(x-1)+\frac{e}{2}(x-1)^2+\frac{e}{6}(x-1)^3$, however I'm unsure how to specifically apply it to the limit in any useful fashion. The discontinuity in the function comes from the denominator so I'm not sure why the expansion of $e^x$ would be of any use in this situation. How to proceed from here?

Comment: Substitute your $P_2(x;1)$ for $e^x$ and see what happens.

Comment: Yes substitute $e^x=e+e(x-1)+e/2(x-1)^2+e/6(x-1)^3+O((x-1)^4)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

[image]

In blue, the function under the limit. In green the function obtained from the Taylor polynomial.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't realize there was an equality and I could just directly substitute. I got it now. :)